# In 'The Moon is a Harsh Mistress' what are Garrison didos?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, the-moon-is-a-harsh-mistress

In numerous locations in Heinlein's Moon he refers to Garrison orbits or Garrison didos.  Based on context I've always interpreted dido as DIrect De-Orbit but having searched for a better definition I've been stymed.  Anyone have an idea what a Garrison orbit is and what a dido is?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> "He answered so calmly that I steadied down. "Farside approach, Man; I'm blind back there. They came in on tight Garrison didoes, skimming the peaks; I barely saw the chop-off for Luna City. The ship at J-City is the only one I can see; the other landings I conclusively infer from the ballistics shown by blip tracks."

DIDO as far as I recall stands for "Dive in Dive Out" (or as modern military term goes, terrain hugging).

---

Curiously enough, someone on Yahoo Answers came up with THIS ([1945 article](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=336&dat=19451108&id=xF0zAAAAIBAJ&sjid=h3kDAAAAIBAJ&pg=6955,829363)) mentioning "[The Dido](http://retrorambling.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/the-dido/)", which is a **snugly-fitting** short sleep garment (a nightie) by a Seattle designer Paula Garrison. So far there seems to be no clear correlation to RAH usage but perhaps someone with access to his papers can clarify if that was the inspiration for the name.

[image: Garrison Dido]

---

Another possible allusion (my own theory) is that the didos RAH may be referring to are semicircles (wave-like path skimming the peaks) which were named after "[Dido's Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DidosProblem.html)" in geometry (referring to Virgil's Dido, Queen of Carthage):

> "Find the figure bounded by a line which has the maximum area for a given perimeter". The solution is a semicircle.

Comment: So what's Garrison mean?  This answers what a dido is, and I think you are right based on usage.  But what is a garrison orbit?

Comment: @chris.w.mclean Sticking a name on a thing like that almost always indicates the person who either invented it or found the practical variant.

Comment: You Can see an advert For a Harrison dido here.  http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=xF0zAAAAIBAJ&sjid=h3kDAAAAIBAJ&pg=768,833960&focus=viewport&output=html_text

Comment: @chris.w.mclean - Per the advert, I think a garrison landing and a garrison orbit are "very short", just like a 'garrison dido'. It's a bit like calling it a miniskirt landing.

Answer (score 5):

I asked a WW2 pilot about it. I was told ‘Garrison flights’ were ones below and between mountains. Called “Terrain hugging” today. Concealed from radar that was new then but did exist. 
 He thought it came from the low altitude flying.  As in: right over the heads of the garrison (troops) stationed below

Answer (score -4):

[DIDO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIDO_%28software%29) is a software tool used to determine optimal control solutions.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little bit more. Namely along the lines of [Bring the content here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/601/bring-the-content-here).

Comment: It seems, um, unlikely that a piece of software developed in 2001 would be referenced in a novel written in 1966.